# Trigonometric simplification with assumptions fails

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions, trigonometry

Consider the following input

```
Assuming[Element[y, Integers], (-1 + E^(I \[Pi] (x + y)))/(-1 + E^(I \[Pi] (x - y)))//FullSimplify]
```

> `(-1 + E^(I \[Pi] (x + y)))/(-1 + E^(I \[Pi] (x - y)))`

the output comes out exactly the same as the input. However, note that for integer `y` we have

$$e^{i\pi(x+y)}=e^{i\pi(x+2y-y)}=\underbrace{e^{2\pi i y}}_{=1}e^{i\pi(x-y)}=e^{i\pi(x-y)}$$

With this I would expect the above mathematica input to return `1` instead of unaltered input.

How to properly simplify this in mathematica?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Assuming[Element[y, Integers],
   (-1 + E^(I π (x + y)))/(-1 + E^(I π (x - y))) // ComplexExpand // FullSimplify]
```

> 1

If `x` is not necessarily real (thanks: Bob Hanlon),

```
Assuming[Element[y, Integers],  
  (-1 + E^(I π (x + y)))/(-1 + E^(I π (x - y)))// ComplexExpand[#, {x}]& // FullSimplify]
```

> 1

Also

```
Assuming[Element[y, Integers], 
   (-1 + E^(I π (x + y)))/(-1 + E^(I π (x - y))) // ExpToTrig // FullSimplify]
```

> 1